# wm7 SHOUTcast song history display

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, stream, shoutcast

I want to display a song list in a textBlock which is retrieved from a site but when I use httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd() I get other results than visiting this site from my computer explorer. 
Here is the code:

```
using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
            string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { textBlock1.Text = results;});
}
//this is the site-> http://5.9.17.81:9996/played.html
```

this is what i get: [image](http://i50.tinypic.com/2aabuk0.png)

Comment: What kind of `other results` ?

Comment: Have you tried to set the `UserAgent` to something like `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)` ?

Comment: No it is HttpWebRequest's property. Or if your class has a `Headers` propery, you can also use `req.Headers.Add("User-Agent","...")`

Comment: I find out how to make it but now I want to show only some specific items! not the whole source-code. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Although this starts to be another question, search for `HtmlAgilityPack`

Comment: thanks a lot! I will figure it out now :D